# getty@tty1.service FAILED - Autologin only shows on TTY1 a flashing _

Tags: debian, tty, getty

I'm working on a minecraft server with OS Ubuntu server 20.04

So far they haven't given me any problems (it's fantastic!), I know some things about linux (some don't exaggerate)

Until something came to me. I'll be out of the house, but I'll have my laptop.

The problem is the following, I want to play minecraft with my friends but every time I start the computer it asks me to enter the password.

Things I'd like to do: Enable Auto-login

What I've already tried: `systemctl edit getty@tty1.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin simao --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

I've also tried replacing the last line with `ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin simao --noclear %I %TERM`

What happens when turning off and on again: On tty1 appears the normal starting and then only a flashing `_`

When running the following command `sudo systemctl --failed`
Gives the following output

```
UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
getty@tty1.service loaded failed failed Getty on tty1
```

Then I ran the following command `sudo systemctl status getty@tty1.service`
And gives the following output "

```
getty@tty1.service - Getty on tty1
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2022-07-25 12:39:35 UTC; 11min ago
       Docs: man:agetty(8)
             man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
             http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
    Process: 1077 ExecStart=/usr/bin/agetty --autologin simao --noclear tty1 38400 linux (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1077 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Succeeded.
Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Jul 25 12:39:35 minecraft-server-simao-vilas systemd[1]: Failed to start Getty on tty1.
```

EDIT: If someone needs more info, only ask and i will edit the post with the info right away (not exactly but the fast i can)

Answer (score 0):

This post is resolved

I executed the following command: `systemctl edit getty@tty1.service`

And added the following code...

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin simao --noclear %I $TERM
```